# How do I store configuration information on my mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mosync

We are building a jquery mobile app to live inside mosync.

When the app first starts up, I want to ask some configuration information and store the config on the device somewhere so it never needs to ask for it again. For example, I want the user to be able to specify the web server that will be server it's web services.

I can't find any documentation on where to look for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mosync supports local storage.

http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html5/localstorage.md.html

Comment: Does that have any benefit over localStorage?

Comment: It's integrated with the framework, other than that, probably not.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.  I was looking at it thinking, "but this *is* local storage!" :)